# Why do so many suggested wiki edits have multiple versions in the queue?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I see a *lot* of cases where a suggested wiki edit will have multiple versions; where each version is a partial version of the next; for example see [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/123543) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/123544), [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/123562) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/123563), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/123535) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/123536):

[image]

Personally, I would expect only the latest one to be shown.

- If both suggested edits get accepted, does the editor get +2 for both edits?
- Should I accept/ reject the lesser edit? At the moment I'm rejecting them for "too minor"...

BTW, I've only seen this occur for wiki edits, and never for post edits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One is the Excerpt/Summary, the other is the Wiki.

[image: Green freehand circles.]

Comment: Stupid me. *puts glasses on*

Comment: Don't worry, I nearly asked the same questions before realizing that. ;)

Answer (score 0):

When a tag excerpt is the only portion that is filled in, some people paste that text into the tag wiki as well, just as a place holder.  I think that's all that's being done in these cases.

I don't necessarily agree with the practice, but I think some users who review the edits are comfortable with that setup, so they get through the approval process.  Newer editors see these examples, and perhaps emulate them.

In that case you cite, there is a bit more text in the tag wiki itself.